# Hypothesis testing in linear regression model for 2 people

Tags: hypothesis-testing, linear-regression

I have been given yearly salaries for two people (A and B) for $40$ years. How could I use linear regression to test whether the salary of the first one rises faster than salary of the other one?

I wanted to do two separated linear regressions $Y_A=n_A+k_A \cdot X+\epsilon_A$ and $Y_B=n_B+k_B \cdot X+\epsilon_B$, where $Y_A$ and $Y_B$ represent salaries. How would I test the null hypothesis $H_0 : k_A=k_B$ against $H_1: k_A \neq k_B$?
I know I could use F-test if all I wanted to test was if $k_A=0$ against $k_A \neq 0$, but don't know how to proceed in this case.

Comment: I think that, once you define "rises faster" precisely it will be clear what computation to perform.  But I don't think it's clear that "rises faster" is the same as "higher slope of regression line", for instance.

Comment: What I am interested in is finding out if their salaries have the same rate of increase or different rates of increase.

Comment: That's not a definition.  Do you mean "same *average* rate"?  Something else?  If all you mean is the average rate, just compute that.

Comment: I don't have a true definition. Both salaries rise approximately linearly, so what I thought I could do is find linear regression lines for each person and then compare the steepness of the slopes.  I don't know linear regression extremely well, should I perhaps combine this two into one single linear regression model somehow?